# ClientResponseException in OpenStack4J on IBM Bluemix Object Storage service

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack-swift, object-storage

I am following this guide to connect to IBM Object Storage for Bluemix with Java:
https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-to-ibm-object-storage-for-bluemix-with-java/

I have double checked the values with the credentials in the service but when I execute the authenticate() method I get following exception:

```
Caused by: ClientResponseException{message=Not Found, status=404, status-code=NOT_FOUND}
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExceptionHandler.mapException(HttpExceptionHandler.java:38)
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExceptionHandler.mapException(HttpExceptionHandler.java:23)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.authenticateV3(OSAuthenticator.java:158)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.invoke(OSAuthenticator.java:70)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:165)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:128)
    at com.servengine.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.postConstruct(ObjectStorageClient.java:32)
    ... 85 more
```

Anyway I can know what is wrong? (URL, userId, password, project, domain, ...)

Thanks

Comment: I have reached out to the recipe author to ask him to look at this question.

Comment: In many of the other guides the AUTH_URL always includes /v3, maybe you are ending up with /v3/v3? `String auth_url = credentials.get("auth_url").toString() + "/v3";`